# python to convert plot to json

Tags: python, json, plot

I am using KaplanMeierFitter method and fitting the data . I am using plot to display the chart . Instead of displaying the chart I want the output in JSON .
Below are my steps

```
kmf=KaplanMeierFitter()

kmf.fit(x,y,label='Kaplan Meier Estimate')

kmf.plot(ci_show=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to save the plot you can do the following:

```
ax = kmf.plot()
ax.get_figure().savefig("savefig.png")
```

Comment: I want to save it as JSON file .

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.save_json allows you to save a matplotlib figure to a json file.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps! Feel free to upvote any of my responses if you felt they were helpful, thanks :)